# HTML Select Tag and changing values in the drop box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a select box, I want the drop down text to show one thing and when it is selected in the box, it shows another.  I do not mean the value tag either. I appreciate all help. Thank you. ^^

For Example:

The Select box when it is not dropped down should say and the value is selected:

T2

Text that shows when the box is dropped down:

T1: (includes T1a, T1b, and T1c): Tumor is 2 cm (3/4 of an inch) or less across.

T2: Tumor is more than 2 cm but not more than 5 cm (2 inches) across.

T3: Tumor is more than 5 cm across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Finally:**

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uhudam/1/edit)**</kbd>

**Option labels are not fully supported** (even if [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_label.asp) thinks they are :) )

**To trick and make it work**, add a first blank `<option>` 
Using jQuery we will

- grab the selected option value,
- Set that value as text and value for the blank `<option>` tag

**jQuery:**

```
$.fn.selectLabelize = function(){
  var v = $(':selected', this).val();
  $('option', this).eq(0).text(v).val(v).prop('selected', true);
};

$('select').each(function(){
  $(this).selectLabelize();
});

$('select').on('change', function(){
    $(this).selectLabelize();
});
```

Taking in consideration a **HTML** like this:

```
<select>
  <option></option>
  <optgroup label="T1">   
      <option value="T1a" selected>a --  Tumor is 2 cm (3/4 of an inch) or less across.</option>
      <option value="T1b">b --  Tumor is 2 cm (3/4 of an inch) or less across.</option>
      <option value="T1c">c --  Tumor is 2 cm (3/4 of an inch) or less across.</option>
  </optgroup> 
  <optgroup label="T2">
      <option value="T2"> Tumor is more than 2 cm but not more than 5 cm (2 inches) across.</option>
  </optgroup> 
  <optgroup label="T3">
      <option value="T3"> Tumor is more than 5 cm across.</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

---

### Using pure JS would be like:

<kbd>**[PURE JS - LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/imakeq/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
function selectLabelize(){
   var v = this.value;
   this.options[0].innerHTML = v ;
   this.options[0].value = v ;
   this.options[0].selected = true;
}

var sel = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
var ev = document.createEvent('Event');
ev.initEvent('change', true, false);

for(var i=0; i<sel.length; i++){
      sel[i].addEventListener('change', selectLabelize ); 
      sel[i].dispatchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: I tried to avoid using a framework on the basis that I didn't expect the OP to be using one ... hence the long way round the problem ... BTW - label can be a custom attribute too :) Did you post a fiddle of it ?? I can't see where it resets the text if the user goes back and re-selects before submitting :)

Comment: @KevinWeber you're welcome really really :) this was a really interesting task!

Comment: @KevinWeber gimme some time, I'll add a pure JS version

Comment: It's ok, I am using jquery in my project anyway.

Comment: One interesting issue, When you have a default selected, it doesnt show the value, but a cut off of the label.

Comment: @Kevin Weber than adjust the CSS :) have you tried to increase the select width (or remove it)

Comment: @KevinW added a pure JS example

Comment: Thank you for the javascript example. CSS sizing will not work as not all contents are the same size, and the styling of my custom css boxes will interfere. I will try to make an onload example of what you made, thank you. ^^

Comment: @KevinWeber edited my answer to make it work properly and on load.

Comment: You are the Bomb! I tend to hire freelancers for various projects. Do you have an email address where I can contact you?

Comment: @KevinWeber visit my profile -> website -> (there's all you need!). Thanks :)

Comment: @KevinWeber ups, forgot to adjust the JS version respectively to jQuery. Done

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, this isn't a simple HTML taslk. It needs a little coding to get the attribute "value" out of the select.

```
<script>
    function flipIt(){
    var sel = document.getElementById('cars');
    var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    for(var x=0; x < sel.options.length; x++) {
      item = sel.options[x];
      var label = item.getAttribute('label'); 
      item.innerHTML = label;
    }
    sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].innerHTML = value;
    alert(value);
  }
</script>

<select id='cars' onChange='flipIt()'>
  <option label="Volvo (Latin for 'I roll')" value="V">Volvo (Latin for "I roll")</option>
  <option label="Saab (Swedish Aeroplane AB)" value="S" selected>Saab (Swedish Aeroplane AB)</option>
  <option label="Mercedes (Mercedes-Benz)" value="M">Mercedes (Mercedes-Benz)</option>
  <option label="Audi (Auto Union Deutschland Ingolstadt)" value="A">Audi (Auto Union Deutschland Ingolstadt</option>
</select>
```

If you pull down the list you will see the long form (the text content between the tags) ... if you select one the little script will return the value in the option attribute. There are, of course, other ways of getting hold of the DOM object but I gave it an id and used getElementById t make it easier for me and clearer to see the code.

Test it here http://jsfiddle.net/radiotrib/gGMLV/2/

Comment: stolen right off the page .. but they missed thebit i had to edit in to make the answer work :)

Comment: Work? how you mean "work"? What browser? BTW you have a typo: `'V"`

Comment: Work according to the context of the question .. the sample I pulled to save ne typing didn't have the value attributes set and I was to damned lazy to go looking any further :) Typo .. que Moi?? .. hehe .. yup I'm over 60 with fat fingers ... it happens all the time, and I can out type this silly Apple keyboard.

Comment: You should test your code not only in IE, but also in all other Modern (better) browsers

Comment: `value="Volvo" value = 'V"` is wrong :) and all the other also.

Comment: Yup .. Now I have to write some code to make the answer right again .. dammit I should have just carried on watching the porn !!

Comment: HAhahahaha :D you made my day! please rewrite your code! I'm really curious to see it work! BTW: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40545

Comment: This still does not work as intended. The text displayed is still the full option text.

Comment: ahhh ... I see now what you mean /... he wants to see the selected VALUE displayed ... hehehe ... much more coding ... BRB ...

Comment: believe it or not, I'm still figuring out how to do it with less code possible

Comment: Me too .. and a toally different way .. BTW are your values reversible in the event of a return and re-select ... yup .. Neat mate :)

Comment: You're very welcome .. it was fun to meet roXon and have a bit of banter :) ... and to dig deep into old skool coding to find a way of doing it. Nowadays i'm too into frameworks to take a look at raw js .. thanks to you too :)